# How to bound the dimension of the conformal algebra of a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, symmetry, conformal-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold, $n \ge 3$. Let $C$ denote the Lie algebra of the conformal vector fields on $M$. It is known that $\dim(C) \le \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$.

Robert Bryant [said here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291171/proofs-that-the-conformal-group-in-dimension-ge-3-is-a-lie-group#comment722790_291183) that this can be proven using local calculations and the Frobenius theorem. I don't see how to implement this approach.

Any ideas? (Or other elementary arguments?)

---

I know that a vector field $V$ is conformal if and only if
$$ \nabla V+(\nabla V)^T=\frac{2}{n} \text{tr}(\nabla V)\text{Id}_{TM}= \frac{2}{n} \text{div} V \cdot  \text{Id}_{TM}.$$

In the case of Killing fields the situation is easier: 
$\nabla V$ is skew-symmetric, and $V$ is determined by $V|_p,\nabla V|_p $, so the dimension of the Killing algebra is not greater than $n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

In the conformal case, it is not true that a conformal field is determined by its value and its covariant derivative at a point. (This time the space of possible $\nabla V|_p$ is of dimension $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1$).

Also, in the conformal case we really need to use somewhere that $n \ge 3$, since for $n=2$ it can be infinite-dimensional.

Comment: As you surely know, strictly speaking one should say "...smooth $n$-dimensional manifold, $n \geq 3$, equipped with a Riemannian metric $g$" or, more to the point, "...conformal structure $\mathbf c$".

Comment: This is probably less elementary than you're aiming for in an answer here, but the claim follows from the fact that there is a bijective correspondence (in fact, equivalence of categories) between, e.g., oriented conformal manifolds and Cartan geometries of type $(\operatorname{SO}(n + 1, 1), P)$ satisfying a certain normalization condition, where $P$ is the stabilizer in $\operatorname{SO}(n + 1, 1)$ of a null ray. In particular, for any conformal structure the algebra of conformal Killing fields has dimension $\leq \dim \operatorname{SO}(n + 1, 1) = \frac{1}{2}(n + 1)(n + 2)$.

Comment: (This perspective and fact are due to Cartan, by the way, though the language is more modern than his.)

Comment: Thanks, this sounds very interesting. Can you elaborate, or give me a reference where to read about the relevant Cartan geometries?

Comment: The standard reference for Cartan geometry is Sharpe's text *Differential Geometry*, but he doesn't treat conformal geometry. (He does treat Moebius geometry, which is similar.) Cap & Slovak's text *Parabolic Geometries I* treats the conformal case (see $\S$1.6), and uses it as a motivational example, but their goals and presentation are much more general.

Comment: There is another method that's morally the same as both the Cartan method and to the one Robert Bryant mentions, but which I find more concrete: For a given metric $g$, one can "prolong" the conformal Killing equation to a closed system of linear PDEs that is equivalent to the conformal Killing equation in the sense that solutions of one correspond to solutions of the other. Since the system is closed and linear, it defines a connection (in fact it is natural in that it is constructed invariantly from $(M, g)$ on a particular vector bundle that turns out to have rank $\frac{1}{2}(n + 1)(n+2)$.

Comment: (cont.) By construction, this connection has the property that parallel sections correspond to solutions of the PDE and hence to a conformal Killing fields. On the other hand, the dimension of the space of parallel sections of a vector bundle is bounded above by the rank of that bundle.

Comment: Thanks, this last approach sounds very nice! Do you perhaps refer to something like this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0926224507000903? If you will have time and energy to elaborate on this prolongation that would great. (I now see that maybe this paper-'Conformal Killing forms on Riemannian manifolds'- is more relevant, the former was more advanced).

Comment: Rod Gover is certainly one of the names that comes to mind for this technique, but that particular paper might be a bit heavy for what you want. Perhaps look at pages 7-10 of [these rough notes](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~eastwood/conformal_notes.pdf) and/or [these slides](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~eastwood/fayetteville1.pdf) by Michael Eastwood.

Comment: (They don't include curvature, though, so the calculations will be messier. I'll try to write it up.)

Comment: @AsafShachar Yes, that's right, though they are treating a generalization of the notion of conformal Killing fields to forms of general rank; the prolonged system I mention is the specialization to $k = 1$ of equation (18) in that paper of Gover-Silhan. But I agree with Anthony that something less general would be a gentler introduction.

Comment: An alternative approach is to use Obata-Ferrand's theorem (solution of Yamabe's problem) that reduces everything to the calculation in the case of the flat metric on $R^n$, which is elementary. Another thing to read is Kobayashi's book "Transformation groups in differential geometry".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that a vector field $X$ is conformal if and only if there is some function $\Lambda$ such that $\nabla X - \Lambda g$ is skew-symmetric. (Throughout this answer I am identifying $TM$ and $T^* M$ by raising and lowering indices implicitly with $g$ - for example here I really mean $\nabla X^\flat - \Lambda g.$) Let $K$ denote this skew tensor, so that we have $$\nabla X = K + \Lambda g.$$

The idea of prolongation is to iterate this process: we now differentiate $K$ and $\Lambda$, introduce new variables (like we did with $K$ and $\Lambda$) for any unknowns, and repeat until the system closes, meaning that we can write the covariant derivative of each of our variables as some "linear combination" of the other variables. Once we have reached this form, we can interpret the system as $D\xi =0$ for some connection $D,$ at which point the dimension of whatever bundle $\xi$ is a section of (which is basically the direct sum of all our variables) gives an upper bound for the dimension of the solution space.

It turns out we only need one more variable in this case. Following [Appendix A2 of these notes by Rod Gover](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.7559.pdf), if we introduce $Q_i = \nabla_i \Lambda + P_{ij} X^j$ where $P$ is the Schouten curvature tensor, then after commuting a bunch of derivatives the system can be written as
\begin{align}
\nabla_i X_j &= K_{ij} + \Lambda g_{ij} \\ 
\nabla_i \Lambda &= Q_i - P_{ij} X^j\\
\nabla_i K_{jk} &= - P_{ij} X_k - P_{ik} X_j - g_{ij} Q_k - g_{ik} Q_j + W_{lijk}X^l \\
\nabla_i Q_j &= -P^k_i K_{jk} - P_{ij} \Lambda - C_{kij} X^k.
\end{align}
Here $W,C$ are the Weyl and Cotton curvature tensors respectively - in particular note that $g,P,W,C$ are all fixed tensor fields, so if we think of $\xi =(X,\Lambda,K,Q)$ as a section of $$E := TM \oplus \mathbb R \oplus \Lambda^2 TM \oplus TM$$ then the  system can be written $\nabla \xi + L(\xi)=0$ for some $L\in \Gamma(T^*M \otimes \operatorname{End}(E)).$ Thus conformal Killing vectors $X$ are in $1-1$ correspondence with the sections of $E$ that are parallel with respect to the linear connection $D = \nabla + L;$ so the space of solutions has dimension at most $$\dim E = n + 1 + \binom n 2+n=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2.$$

The assumption $n>2$ is used somewhere in the calculation for $\nabla Q$: you can see the easy version (for a flat metric) in [these slides by Michael Eastwood](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~eastwood/fayetteville1.pdf). (I wussed out and don't feel like doing the hard version of the calculation myself - hopefully you can work it out.) In the case $n=2$, I believe you would find that the system never closes, no matter how long you prolong the prolongation.

Edit: I recalled receiving a nice handout at a talk of Michael's a few years ago, so I dug it out of the closet. I think its introduction is a better reference than either of my links above, and it can be found [online here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0402100.pdf). It includes some well-written motivation as well as the details of the calculation I omitted.

Comment: This is a very nice exposition! I'll add that we can regard the "flat model" of conformal geometry in dimension $n \geq 3$ to be an $\operatorname{SO}(n + 1, 1)$-invariant conformal structure on $\operatorname{SO}(n + 1, 1) / P \cong \Bbb S^n$, where $P$ is the stabilizer in $\operatorname{SO}(n + 1, 1)$ of a null ray in $\Bbb R^{n + 1, 1}$. Then, we can identify $E$ with the associated bundle $\operatorname{SO}(n + 1, 1) \times_P \mathfrak{so}(n + 1, 1)$ and the connection on $E$ with the connection induced on that bundle by the Maurer-Cartan form on $\operatorname{SO}(n + 1, 1)$.

Comment: (cont.) In that setting, any choice of metric $g$ in the conformal class determines an identification $E = TM \oplus \Bbb R \oplus \Lambda^2 TM \oplus TM$ as in the answer, and this corresponds exactly to the $\mathfrak{so}(n, \Bbb R)$-module decomposition $\mathfrak{so}(n + 1, 1) \cong \Bbb R^n \oplus \Bbb R \oplus \mathfrak{so}(n, \Bbb R) \oplus (\Bbb R^n)^*$. The idea of the Cartan approach to conformal geometry is to generalize this entire picture suitably to "nonflat" geometry.

Comment: Thanks! I really need to put the effort in and learn Klein/Cartan geometry properly sometime, it all seems so beautiful.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thanks. That last reference is indeed fantastic. BTW, if I am not mistaken the proof there (Example 1.2.2 ) shows also that a conformal vector field is uniquely determined by its $2$-jet at a single point (if the manifold is connected). This is nice; I wonder if there is an analogous result for conformal maps.

Comment: @AsafShachar: right - this is simply because parallel sections are determined by their value at a point, and $\xi(p)$ is determined by $j^2_pX.$ (I guess we were already using this fact implicitly when we bounded the solution space by the fiber dimension.) The analogous 2-rigidity for conformal maps is indeed true, though I'm not sure if it can be proved by similar means.